# Sorting the output of a foreach loop by size in java

Tags: java

I have a foreach loop which iterates through a series of words. It needs to print them out by size.

```
for (String word : words2) {
    maxLength = 1;
    if(words1.contains(word)&&word.length()>maxLength){
        ++maxLength;
    System.out.print(word + ",\r");
}
```

My question is if there is any way to do this in java?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. But you would usually sort the elements _before_ iterating.

Comment: You have a collection that you want to sort.  When you Google something like "Java sort collection", do you find anything?  What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: You will only ever calculate `maxLength` as 1 or 2 from this code (or whatever `maxLength` is initialized to, in the case that `words2` is empty).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to sort array of words by word length. To do so you can use stream API of Java 8:

```
String arr[] = new String[] {"a", "asd", "as"};
String[] sorted = Arrays.stream(arr)
                      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or you can just print them straight away:

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Arrays.sort()` be better than streaming?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In this particular example it's an overkill. But it adds more flexibility in case he'd like to sort by some other criteria. Also stream operations do not mutate the array, which also could be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array you could use Java 8 to sort them as follows:

```
String[] words = "This is the phrase I want to split by length".split(" ");
Arrays.sort(words, (word1, word2) -> Integer.compare(word1.length(), word2.length()));

for (String s : words) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
I
is
to
by
the
This
want
split
phrase
length
```

**OR** a better approach as suggested by @Andreas in the comments below:

```
Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)` be better?

Comment: @Andreas actually yes, I just edited the answer to add your suggestion, I'm not that familiar with Java 8 yet, so I do what I can with what I know (until now), thank you for your feedback :)